# Convert multiple list of data into data table based on common property in c#

Tags: c#, list, linq, datatable

I have multiple list of signal datas with timestamp.
for ex SignalA contain list of {time, value} object. Similarly, SignalB contain list of {time, value} object.
I can have any number of such list, it is not fixed. Can have 2,3,4 or any...

```
SignalA = [{time="10:00", value=1},{time="11:00", value=2}, {time="12:00", value=3}]
SignalB = [{time="10:00", value=2},{time="11:00", value=3}, {time="12:00", value=1}]
SignalC = [{time="10:00", value=3},{time="11:00", value=1}, {time="12:00", value=2}]
```

Now I want to create data table with time, signalB, signalA columns. singalA column contain value property from SignalA object, similarly singnalB column contain value property from SignalB object at specific time.

```
Datatable = [{time="10:00", SignalA=1, SignalB=2, SignalC=3}, {time="11:00", SignalA=2, SignalB=3, SignalC=1}, {time="12:00", SignalA=3, SignalB=1, SignalC=2}]
```

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: are the lists SignalA and SignalB sorted by time, ascending? Is it possible that a specific time value is present in one but not in the other?

Comment: What is the datatype of the elements of SignalA and SignalB?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues Yes it will sorted on time, ascending & it is possible that a specific time value is present in one but not in the other, in that case we can skip that time value. 
Also, number of list is not fixed, it can be any ex. 2, 3, 4 etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your lists `SignalA` and `SignalB` are sorted and both have the same values of `time`, this can be easily solved with [`Linq.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-8.0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Test {
  static void Main() {
    var SignalA = new[] { new {time="10:00", value=1}, new {time="11:00", value=2}, new {time="12:00", value=3} };
    var SignalB = new[] { new {time="10:00", value=2}, new {time="11:00", value=3}, new {time="12:00", value=1} };
    var Datatable = SignalA.Zip(SignalB, (a, b) => new {time=a.time, SignalA=a.value, SignalB=b.value});
    
    foreach (var entry in Datatable) {
        Console.WriteLine(entry);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
{ time = 10:00, SignalA = 1, SignalB = 2 }
{ time = 11:00, SignalA = 2, SignalB = 3 }
{ time = 12:00, SignalA = 3, SignalB = 1 }
```